# Analytical Matrix Inversion

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix of the form $A = bI - J$ where
  1. $b$ is a large positive constant so that $A$ is positive definite
  2. $J_{ij} = 0$ for $i=j$ and follows a power law off-diagnol. In index notation:

$$
A_{ij} = (b\delta_{ij} - \frac{J_0(1-\delta_{ij})}{|i-j|^\alpha}) \text{ where } \alpha \geq 1
$$

Is it possible to calculate $A^{-1}$ analytically? I hope to show that $A^{-1}$ also follows some type of power law as well as is suggested by numerics.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Of course it is possible by solving linear equations. Maybe you see some law if you try. But I'm afraid that's not what you want to know?

Comment: I want to know it for any finite dimension.

Comment: @Travis Sorry, I must be misunderstanding. When you say "solving linear equations" do you mean Gauss-Jordan elimination? Doesn't this depend on having a specific matrix to perform the process on?

Comment: @Travis Thanks! That last idea worked pretty well.